# Is this expression to get a nested array possible with Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

In a previous question some users commented as a response to access a nested array that this is possible:

`fun getMovies(): Single<Response<List<Result>>>`

But every time that I try to implement it it gives me the Error message:

`No type arguments expected for class Response`

This is my Model Class:

```
data class Response(
   val page: Int?,
   val total_results: Int?,
   val total_pages: Int?,
   val results: List<Result>
) {
   //@Entity
   data class Result(
       val popularity: Double?,
       val vote_count: Int?,
       val video: Boolean?,
       val poster_path: String?,
       val id: Int?,
       val adult: Boolean?,
       val backdrop_path: String?,
       val original_language: String?,
       val original_title: String?,
       val genre_ids: List<Int>?,
       val title: String?,
       val vote_average: Double?,
       val overview: String?,
       val release_date: String?
   )
}
```

My Api Interface

```
package com.example.moviesapplication.model

import io.reactivex.Single
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface MoviesApi {
   @GET("/3/discover/movie?api_key=${apiKey}&language=en-US&sort_by=popularity.desc&include_adult=false&include_video=false&page=1")
   fun getMovies():  Single<List<Response.Result>>
}
```

So if anyone know if the expression stated is possible or something similar, please let me know.

Comment: Can I see your entire interface for api, I want to see what package that you import.

Comment: Updated with my interface

Comment: So what is return type of `getMovies()` between `Single<Response<List<Result>>>` or `Single<List<Response.Result>>`?

Comment: Ah yeah sorry for the mess I've been trying stuff, I guess it's 
 `Single<Response<List<Result>>>`  since it's what some people commented

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you import wrong package, maybe you import `Response` of `Okhttp` instead of your `Response data class` since `Response` of `OkHttp` doesn't want type argument.

At the same time your Response is a bit strange, Your Response class does not want type argument. Your response should be something like

```
fun getMovies():  Single<Response>
```

instead of

```
fun getMovies():  Single<Response<List<Result>>>
```

I think it become like this because you confuse between `Response` of `Retrofit` that need type argument `[Response<T>]` and your Response data class that does not need type argument.

---

**Recommend**

I thinks it will be better if your `Response` class is some think like

```
data class Response<T>(
    val page: Int?,
    val total_results: Int?,
    val total_pages: Int?,
    val results: List<T> // or val results: T
)
```

Because if you have lots pf responses that have Base like `Response` class but, its result have different model or list (something like`List<ResultMovie>` or `List<...>`). You only need to pass T to your Base model like `Response<Result>`. You not need to repeat to declare Response every time you have Base model like this, and it also easier to manage or fixes later.

Comment: The thing is I'm trying to access a nested Array that is why, that expression was recommended by some developers but it doesn't seem to work, so the only solution is to get the whole Response?

Comment: It's up to what your API return between `List<Result>` or `List<Response>`. If your API return `List<Result>`, you can declare return type of `getMovies()` to `List<Response.Result>` but if your API return `List<Response>` you will need to access `List<Result>` from each of 'Response' from `List<Response>`.

Comment: Sorry for my terrible English Skill, If's it make you confuse.

Comment: I also have some recommend, please read it again after 5-10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Response` class doesn't have any generic parameters, and that's what the error is pointing out.

You can return `Single<Response>` and the array will always be a List of `Result`, it doesn't have any dynamic types.